# Remove NAs from dataframe except in one column R

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe:

```
column1 <- c(400, 500, 350, 70, NA, NA, 500, 350, 70)
column2 <- c(NA, 67, 23, 45, 78, 123, 54, 123, 898)
column3 <- c(412, 4, 5, 6, 1, 689, 90, 12, NA)
column4 <- c("IMC", "VMC", NA, NA, NA, NA, "IMC", "VMC", "IMC")
data1 <- data.frame(column1, column2, column3, column4)
```

It looks like this:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
400      NA       412      IMC
500      67       4        VMC
350      23       5        NA
70       45       6        NA
NA       78       1        NA
NA       123      689      NA
500      54       90       IMC
350      123      12       VMC
70       898      NA       IMC
```

Question: Is it possible to remove the rows with NA's from column 1, 2 and 3, but not from column 4? So my output will look like this:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
500      67       4        VMC
350      23       5        NA
70       45       6        NA
500      54       90       IMC
350      123      12       VMC
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `complete.cases()` on the first three columns and then do a `subset`:

```
data1[complete.cases(data1[, 1:3]), ]
  column1 column2 column3 column4
2     500      67       4     VMC
3     350      23       5    <NA>
4      70      45       6    <NA>
7     500      54      90     IMC
8     350     123      12     VMC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have an additional question: what if I want to remove the rows with NA's from column 1, 2 and 4, but not from column 3? (can I use `data1[complete.cases(data1[, 1,2,4]), ]` in this case?

Comment: `data1[complete.cases(data1[, c(1, 2, 4)]), ]` should be fine. You need to specify the column selection as a vector and that's where the `c` comes from.

Answer (score 2):

A `library(dplyr)` approach :

```
data1 %>% filter(complete.cases(.[,-4]))
```

or

```
data1 %>% filter(complete.cases(.[,-3]))
```

if you want to keep NA's in column 3

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table` by specifying the columns in `.SDcols`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[data1[, complete.cases(.SD), .SDcols = column1:column3]]
#   column1 column2 column3 column4
#1:     500      67       4     VMC
#2:     350      23       5      NA
#3:      70      45       6      NA
#4:     500      54      90     IMC
#5:     350     123      12     VMC
```